# Raspberry PI 3 Python not writing correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I am now playing around with my Raspberry PI using Telegram Bot. 
What I want to do is simple: My Telegram Bot will have a few functions, at the moment he is only responding to me but I would like to make some kind of "registration" system. There is a text file with five Chat ID's and the passwords that look like this:

```
000000000
000000000
000000000
56*******
000000000
password
```

And the code is:

```
def usradd(chat_id)
    count = 0
    f = open("home/pi/...")
    e = f.readline()

    while count < 6
        if '000000000' in e:
           print >> f, str(chat_id)
           bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "You now have access")
           count = 5
           f.close()
        elif '000000000' not in e and count != 5:
           count += 1
           e = f.readline()
        elif count == 5
           count = 6
           bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Sorry, no more space for users")
           f.close()
```

It almost works as it should. It does not overwrite the first `000000000` but the second one. And when it reaches the last one, it even overwrites the "password".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: For one thing, one of `'000000000' in e` and `'000000000' not in e` will always be true, so your last `elif` will never execute.

Comment: `e = readline()` is going to throw a `NameError`.

Comment: You should probably change the last `elif` to `if`. And you should probably also break out from the while loop when you have written an entry (provided I understand what you are trying to do).

Comment: Sorry I forgot something, code is now the same as in the python file

Answer (score 0):

When you have read the first line, the file pointer is on the start of the second line. Therefore the write to the file will happen there. You need to reposition the file pointer if you want to write on a particular location in the file.

For example, to start writing at the start of the file:

```
f.seek(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to matli for the hint with f.seek(0,0)

This is the code now and it works:

```
def usradd(chat_id)
count = 0
f = open("home/pi/...")
e = f.readline()

while count < 6
    if '000000000' in e:
       r = 10 * count
       f.seek (r , 0)
       print >> f, str(chat_id)
       bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "You now have access")
       count = 5
       f.close()
    elif '000000000' not in e and count != 5:
       count += 1
       e = f.readline()
    elif count == 5
       count = 6
       bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Sorry, no more space for users")
       f.close()
```